# Revisions not showing

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, revisions-list

On Area 51, when you go to the revisions screen, you can see the number of revisions that has been made and who made what. However, the actual revisions are missing, not just in style but the actual content. It looks like it should be gotten with Ajax, but I don't get any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Here is an example : http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/8695/revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now -- thanks.

Comment: FYI: it says "Return to Answer" at the top of the revisions list.

Comment: @Jon Seigel Ahh good catch -- it's fixed now.