# Revisions of area51 example questions not working

Tags: bug, area-51, revisions-list, example-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revisions not showing.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54313/revisions-not-showing)

I got the notification of a revision at [this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/4973/revisions) but all I see is empty revisions and the edit links link to a 404 (http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/4973/edit/818ad9e6-73ab-42c7-83db-8579511ebaa7 and http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/4973/edit/5c38f37c-01b9-4ee8-9678-534bd7e58eb8). I observed this before at another question.